# How to make Youtube videos have different player?

Tags: php, html, css, youtube

How can I make Youtube videos as below design:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/2y4nJ0V.png]

Now please note that picture just an example basically I want simply to change Youtube video design on website where I will embed the video. Please also be aware that any information would count as help since I don't know from what to start and any example would be equal as answer.

Comment: What have you tried so far? I don't belive you can do it since you embed a iframe

Comment: Probably can be done, but I doubt YouTube makes it easy. Best bet is to probably use a 3rd party application. Google [custom youtube player](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=custom%20youtube%20player) and look around, there appears to be several options.

Comment: you can embed video on only the popular way as people used to do on Youtube api page i found actually more than 4 ways to do it and found some articles how to do with JW payer so basically if i want custom design i need create custom JW player theme which is not easy thing so this idea is plan b now @Mark M gave very simple idea how to search basically with my keywords i didn';t get similar results will check it out further thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's two way you can change the way how Youtube controls looks like.

1.add parameters.

In the video page you want to use, click`share` and `embed`, below the `<iframe>` code.

You can change video size, show suggested videos when this one finishes or not, hide controls.

```
<iframe width="640" height="360" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/0ES4oNo8B5I" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

put a `?` after the url to add your first parameter `autoplay=1`, if you want to put more parameters, add `&` followed by other parameter.

```
https://www.youtube.com/embed/0ES4oNo8B5I?autoplay=1&controls=0
```

This code means autoplay video and hide controls.

Here's parameters reference you can look up.

[YouTube Embeded Player](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#autoplay)

2.This one needs more tech like jQuery. There's no short way to cover this, so I put the link here.

[Making a Custom YouTube Video Player With YouTube’s APIs](http://tutorialzine.com/2010/07/youtube-api-custom-player-jquery-css/)

Answer (score 1):

i don't think you can change the youtube player, but what you could do is
dig on the video and get the real link for mp4 file (you can try the [YouTube-Downloader](https://github.com/jeckman/YouTube-Downloader)) by [jeckman](https://github.com/jeckman) or something Similar then you could do a video player like Videojs or any other player with that link without saving the file on your server